# Sklearn - Access scalar attributes after it is passed through pipeline and wrapped in GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a pipeline and like this that I pass to GridSearchCV, how can I access the attributes of the scaler from clf?

```
pipe = Pipeline([
        ('scale', MinMaxScaler()),
        ('clf', tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(presort=True))
    ])

pipe_param_grid = {
            'clf__min_samples_split': [2, 4, 6],
            'clf__random_state': [38, 40, 42, 44],
            'clf__max_depth': [4],
            'clf__min_samples_leaf': [2, 4],
          }

clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe,param_grid=pipe_param_grid)
```

- Python: 2.7.10
- scikit-learn: 0.18.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I can access the step attributes like this:

```
clf.best_estimator_.named_steps['scale'].scale_
```